# factory_girl ignores the namespace of the class that it's creating an instance of

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, mongomapper

I've searched a lot, but could not find any similar problem to mine. Suppose we've got namespaced models, `UserManagement::User` and `UserManagement::Session`.
Here are factories for theses models:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user, class: UserManagement::User do
    UserManagement::User.set_database_name 'db_name'

    id '000000000a00a000a0000001'
    login 'Mark'
    password 'password'
    password_confirmation 'password'
    data { {} }
    session { build(:session) }

    initialize_with { new(attributes) }
  end
end
```

and

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :session, class: UserManagement::Session do
    token '0000-0000-0000'
    expiration { Time.zone.now + 30.minutes }
  end
end
```

When I perform `FactoryGirl.lint`, I am receiving `user - uninitialized constant Session (NameError)` which is, as I guess, problem with namespacing, because `:user` factory tries to look for `Session` model and not for `UserManagement::Sesssion`.

Comment: try the following:
`factory :session, class: 'UserManagement::Session' do`

Comment: I have tried that earlier - unfortunately didn't worked.

Comment: Are these Mongoid models? What does "set_database_name" do, and why is it one model but not the other?

Comment: These are MongoMapper models. set_database_name sets actual database name(that's because I am using dynamic db naming in my app). So, if I set db name once, it is held for Session model too.

Comment: You should answer your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I found out solution of that problem. As I guess MongoMapper isn't very module - friendly, as ActiveRecord. I had to explicitly define which class name my Session association is, even if it is in the same module scope. So the solution is one :session, class_name: 'UserManagement::Session' Thanks everyone for any help!